# Encoding txt to xml

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I'm generating xml from txt files, but when i use an UTF-8  Encoding, it isn't work with russian language; i see only some charachters and not a text in xml tags, like this(that happens when i use russian text file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><document>
<el Id="1">
    <text Id="1">ï»¿Ð¡Ñ€ÐµÐ´Ð¸ Ð´Ñ€ÑƒÐ³Ð¸Ñ… Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐºÑ‚Ð¾Ð² Ð¼Ð¾Ð³ÑƒÑ‚ Ð±Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ�Ð¾Ð·Ð´Ð°Ð½Ñ‹ , Ñ�Ð¾Ð·Ð´Ð°ÑŽÑ‚Ñ�Ñ� Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐºÑ‚Ñ‹ Ð²Ñ‹Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð½Ð¸Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ�,</text>
</el>
<el Id="2">
    <text Id="2">ÐžÑ‚Ñ‡ÐµÑ‚Ñ‹ Ð¿Ð¾ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÐµÐºÑ‚Ð°Ð¼ Ð¸ Ð´Ð¾Ñ�Ñ‚ÑƒÐ¿Ð½Ñ‹ TM Ð¸ Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð¼Ð¸Ð½Ð¾Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ð¸Ð¸ ÑƒÐ¿Ñ€Ð°Ð²Ð»Ñ�ÑŽÑ‚Ñ�Ñ�. Ð¡Ð¾Ð·Ð´Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ</text>
</el>



public void initXML() throws ParserConfigurationException,TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {
    // JAXP + SAX
    SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    th = tf.newTransformerHandler();
    Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
    // XML ausgabe
    serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    th.setResult(out);
    th.startDocument();
    atts = new AttributesImpl();
    th.startElement("", "", "document", atts);
}
```

with ISO-8859-1 it isn't work too. Wich Encoding can i use, to solve that?

it works now, thank you all for help

Comment: You haven't shown the code which writes each <text> element's content.  Note that a TransformerHandler is meant to be used as a listener;  its methods should not be called directly.  You should obtain a Transformer from a TransformerFactory, and you should call the Transformer's `transform` method.

Comment: thank you vor answering, do you mean this: Transformer transformer = null;
        try {
          transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
          // the transformer cannot be created
          System.err.println(tce.getMessage());
          System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            transformer.transform( file, out);
          } catch (TransformerException te) {
            
          }

Comment: The correct way to obtain a TransformerFactory is with `TransformerFactory.newInstance()`.  The [`Transformer.transform` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29) expects a Source as the first argument, so you can't pass a file directly, but you can pass `new StreamSource(file)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have wrong encoding in txt file. Open file in advanced editor and check it.

Comment: it has utf8 too, i checked it